# JsonObjectRequest not work in onItemSelected spinner

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I want use JsonObjectRequest in onItemSelected spinner when set item spinner get json but JsonObjectRequest not work and not display nothing,how to can use JsonObjectRequest in onItemSelected?please help me

**my code**

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                    int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                    int id_category = jsonObject.getInt("id_category");
                    int id_speaker = jsonObject.getInt("id_speaker");
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                    String category_name = jsonObject.getString("category_name");
                    String speaker_name = jsonObject.getString("speaker_name");

                    Item_zakerin_any itemzakeran = new Item_zakerin_any(id, id_category, name, id_speaker, image, speaker_name, category_name);
                    list_zakeran_any.add(itemzakeran);
                    az = new adapter_zakeran_any(mcontext, list_zakeran_any);

                    rv.setAdapter(az);
                    hidepDialog();

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            hidepDialog();

        }
    });

    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your adapter in the loop. Move it out like:

```
try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                int id_category = jsonObject.getInt("id_category");
                int id_speaker = jsonObject.getInt("id_speaker");
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                String category_name = jsonObject.getString("category_name");
                String speaker_name = jsonObject.getString("speaker_name");

                Item_zakerin_any itemzakeran = new Item_zakerin_any(id, id_category, name, id_speaker, image, speaker_name, category_name);
                list_zakeran_any.add(itemzakeran);

            }

            az = new adapter_zakeran_any(mcontext, list_zakeran_any);
            rv.setAdapter(az);
            hidepDialog();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           hidepDialog();
        }
```

Also don't forget to hide your dialog if it hits exception so they are not permanently blocked.

Comment: Please supply additional information. I will need to see the XML file that has your Spinner in it. I will need to see your Activity file where you find the spinner and assign it to an object. I will also need to see your custom adapter adapter_zakeran_any to ensure there are not any issues in there as you decided to supply custom layout UI for the spinner so I would need to see your create View and your Bind View routines, unless it is listview then I need to see your create and getView routines. So share the rest of the code and I will help.